# why the set print value is ordered when the loop nums become large?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.8

it is python 3.8, when input 10, the print(s) is random, but when input 900, the print(s) is ordered same as print(sorted(s))

```py
import random

s = set()

for i in range(int(input("loop nums:\n"))):
    vv = random.randint(1, 1000)
    s.add(vv)

print(s)
print(sorted(s))
```

Comment: Also works in 3.6 for 453 and above. Charming.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the probability of sorted output changes as a sigmoid from 0 to 1 as the number of additions changes from ~375 to ~455.